# probability parameter kf $t$

Tags: probability

Suppose we define a probability on some sample space, dependent on a parameter $t$. Let $E$ and $F$ be two events. Suppose that for each of these events, their probability is an increasing function of $t$.

Does this mean that the probability of the union of $E$ and $F$ is an increasing function of $t$?

It seems intuitive but I don't see how to prove it.

**context**:

Suppose we have some sets $A_1,...A_n$. let's choose a random subset $X$ of their union as follows: for each $x$ in their union, place $x$ in $X$ with probability $t$.

Therefore, for each subset $C$ of their union, $C$ is a subset of $X$ with probability $t^{|C|}$.

Consider the event $E$ = ($A_1$ is a subset of $X$) $\cup\dots\cup$ ($A_n$ is a subset of $X$).

I want to show that $p(E)$ is an increasing function of $t$ (on the segment [0,1])

I apologize for the way this is written, I am writing from my phone

Comment: Hi, you are confused in more than one regard, it seems. Can you specify the context.

Comment: @Will M. context added

Comment: You should be careful with your formulation. Just asking that the *probability* of $E_t$ and $F_t$ is increasing is not enough. A (very artificial) counterexample might be considering $X$ a uniform on $[0,1]$, $E_t = \{X < t\}$ and $F_t = E_{1-t}^c$ for $t \in [0, 1/2]$ and $F_t = E_t$ for $t \in (1/2, 1]$.

Comment: I am pretty sure I have seen the question on the context here on math stackexchange, but I can't find it.... However, the solution was about using inclusion exclusion principle and deriving the expression obtained (essentially we are deriving a polynomial)

Comment: @Daniel: actually the original problem was to prove that the polynomial expression given by the inclusion exclusion principle is an increasing function of t, and one possible method seems to be interpreting that expression probabilistically and continuing as i tried to above. another possible idea is to derive the expression and show that the result is positive, which i have managed to do only in the case where the A_i are mutuslly disjoint.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou, now I seem to recall better the problem in question. If the problem is only to show that $p(E)$ is increasing in $t$ with the definition given above, you can use what we call coupling. Let $U_x$ be independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ and $X_t = \{x; U_x < t\}$ be a random set. Then, $E_t = \cup_{i=1}^n \{A_i \subset X_t\}$ and now it is clear that $\mathbb{P}[E_t]$ is increasing, since by construction $X_t \subset X_s$ whenever $t \le s$.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou, complementing the previous comment; the main point here is that for every $t$ we are using the same random variables $U_x$ to generate the set $X_t$.

Comment: @Daniel: i understand now, thank you. thus, i ran into a problem trying to demonstrate that the probability of the event $E$ was increasing in $t$ due to a sloppy formulation of how $X$ is constructed. your rigorous method clears things up.